# How to trim a message recieved from tcpClient.GetStream()

Tags: visual-studio-2010, vba

I have the following code which recieves input from an agent application I have also developed.

I am trying to trim down all the additional whitespace that comes from the agent but regardless of what I do, the result still has a length of 8192. here is what I have so far...

```
Private Sub HandleClientComm(ByVal client As Object)
    Dim tcpClient As TcpClient = DirectCast(client, TcpClient)
    Dim clientStream As NetworkStream = tcpClient.GetStream()

    Dim message As Byte() = New Byte(8191) {}
    Dim bytesRead As Integer
    Dim result As String
    While True
        message = New Byte(8191) {}
        bytesRead = 0
        Try
            bytesRead = clientStream.Read(message, 0, 8191) 'blocks until a client sends a message
        Catch
            bytesRead = 0
        End Try
        result = ""
        result = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(message).ToString.Trim
        Logger(result.Length)
        Logger("""" & result & """", "RECV")
```

the result.Length = 8192 and the result itself is still a large string with trailing whitespace. I have tried many things to try and get rid of it..

```
result = CType(result,String).Trim

result = trim(result)
```

The result never changes, and now I'm stuck.

Any help, appreciated of course!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It was null bytes... This fixed it.

```
result = result.Trim(result.Trim(chr(0)))
```